# How can I quickly test dao,service for springboot,junit can't meet my needs

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

SpringbootTest loads the context every time and finds out the dao layer,service, etc
@runwith does this put context in the cache,
Why does it still take 4.5 seconds to test once? How to solve this problem if there are many operations in one operation

Answer (score 0):

This is why you should limite the integration tests and use mainly unit tests when in developpement and put integration in the end , so you don't wast your time and your teams time everytime you need to build . What you could do (using the @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) ) to load the conetext for all the test that needs it is to create an integration ClassTest and put all the the tests inside of it so the context will be loaded for all of them just once .

Comment: Is there any way to do a single quick test,Such as connecting to a running spring context, or loading the spring context only once, hot deploy at development time

Comment: well the way is using @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and this will run the single test if you choose too .

Comment: It takes about five seconds, which is too bad